# How to disable dojo errors in eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, dojo

Doing some web development and using DOJO for that. Eclipse doesn't compile project because of DOJO errors. I already change all java script validation errors to warning or even to ignore, but still see errors.

Is there anyway do disable those errors?
Also is there a DOJO plugin for Eclipse? Cannot find anything.

Comment: what errors are you speaking of? can you give some examples?  Some versions of Eclipse might be configured to do HTML validation, and some of the tests and examples are not strictly validating, though they should still work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that using the source distribution of Dojo, they include some Java (not JavaScript) tools for minification etc (in the "util" folder).

You can either set your build to ignore the folder, resolve their issues / dependencies or remove the extra folder from your project - leaving "dojo", "dojox" and "dijit" - which is all that's contained in a production build anyway.